# XPath: apply function to all matches?

Tags: xpath

So I have an XPath expression to get at the attribute value I'm interested in:

```
//ElementName/@AttributeName
```

I want just the value of that attribute as a string.  I can do this:

```
string(//ElementName/@AttributeName)
```

but that only applies the function to the first node.  I want to get the result of applying `string()` to *all* of the matches, concatenated together (I'm using `xmllint` from the command line, which just prints out the results of the expression, so it doesn't need to be a structured type result). I thought this might work:

```
//ElementName/string(./@AttributeName)
```

But that gives me a syntax error, as do the variations I tried. So at the moment, I'm doing this:

```
count=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//ElementName/@AttributeName)' file.xml)
for (( i=1; i<=count; ++i )); do
   echo "$(xmllint --xpath "string((//ElementName/@AttributeName)[$i])" file.xml)"
done
```

which seems ... inefficient, at least.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 (or XQuery 1.0) and later you can use the approach of `//ElementName/@AttributeName/string()` to get a sequence of all string values or `string-join(//ElementName/@AttributeName, '')` to concatenate them all together. But in XPath 1.0 you always need to go to the host language as you have done.

Comment: And it appears that `libxml`, which `xmllint` is just a CLI interface to, still only supports XPath 1.0.  OK.  Thanks!