# Scrapy - handle different versions of h1

Tags: python, scrapy

i'am trying to scrap a page where some sites have a normal H-Tag and other Sites have other Tags inside the H-Tags.

some examples:

```
<h1>Text</h1>
<h1><a href="">Text</a></h1>
<h1><span>Text</span></h1>
<h1><span>Text</span><span>Text2</span></h1>
and many more...
```

must i write a check for every html-tag by my self, or is there a nice way in scrapy?

a nasty and unwanted way would be:

```
h1 = response.xpath('//h1').extract()
if '<a' in h1[0]:
    h1 = json.dumps(response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract(), ensure_ascii=False)
elif '<span' in h1[0]:
    h1 = json.dumps(response.xpath('//h1/span/text()').extract(), ensure_ascii=False)
else:
    h1 = json.dumps(response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract(), ensure_ascii=False)
```

[image: Only one Element eith string()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one nice way to use `string()` from XPath:

```
response.xpath('string(//h1)').extract_first()
```

Comment: that works, can i do this in one line for all h1 tags on the page?

Comment: Just use `extract()` instead

Comment: tryed this, but gets only the first

Comment: tryed it in the shell, see screenshot in my question

Comment: @Tobias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400915/xpath-apply-function-to-all-matches

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy isn't concerned with this but the Query language you're using.
Using XPath, this will work:

```
response.xpath('//h1//text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all the tags using

```
response.xpath('//h1//text()').extract()
```